# Angular2 Webpack Summernote not binding to Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, summernote, es6-modules

I have jquery configured  using the webpack.ProviderPlugin like so

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery'
})
```

]

And summernote imported after bootstrap in my vendor.js like so

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'summernote';
```

When I create a summernote control in my component, the dropdown buttons in the toolbar don't work, the tooltips over the buttons don't display, and in general nothing is bound to the bootstrap js correctly. The only places I have seen people with this problem online they say it is because of multiple versions of jquery running, but I'm fairly sure I only have jquery loaded once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add this:  
`const $ = require('jquery');` before:
`import 'bootstrap';`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately same result though.